# Javascript- Reading data from an array with some object in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script

I cant deal with a problem to read the datas int an other object.

This is the data. This is sadly not in english but i think its doesent matter.

```js
[
  {
    termeknev: 'Adatmegosztó',
    besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42',
    mennyegys: 'hó',
    menny: 1,
    nettoegysegar: '543,30',
    nettoar: '543,30',
    afakulcs: 5,
    afaertek: '27,16',
    bruttoar: '570,46',
    id: 1,
  },
  [
    {
      termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés',
      besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12',
      mennyegys: 'hó',
      menny: 1,
      nettoegysegar: '6000,00',
      nettoar: '6000,00',
      afakulcs: 27,
      afaertek: '1620,00',
      bruttoar: '7620,00',
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés',
      besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12',
      mennyegys: 'hó',
      menny: 1,
      nettoegysegar: '1000,00',
      nettoar: '1000,00',
      afakulcs: 27,
      afaertek: '270,00',
      bruttoar: '1270,00',
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start',
      besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42',
      mennyegys: 'hó',
      menny: 1,
      nettoegysegar: '2669,29',
      nettoar: '2669,29',
      afakulcs: 5,
      afaertek: '133,46',
      bruttoar: '2802,75',
      id: 4,
    },
    {
      termeknev: 'Korlátlan sebesség&adat opció',
      besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42',
      mennyegys: 'hó',
      menny: 1,
      nettoegysegar: '2362,20',
      nettoar: '2362,20',
      afakulcs: 5,
      afaertek: '118,11',
      bruttoar: '2480,31',
      id: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés',
      besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12',
      mennyegys: 'hó',
      menny: 1,
      nettoegysegar: '6000,00',
      nettoar: '6000,00',
      afakulcs: 27,
      afaertek: '1620,00',
      bruttoar: '7620,00',
      id: 12,
    },
    {
      termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés',
      besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12',
      mennyegys: 'hó',
      menny: 1,
      nettoegysegar: '1000,00',
      nettoar: '1000,00',
      afakulcs: 27,
      afaertek: '270,00',
      bruttoar: '1270,00',
      id: 13,
    },
    {
      termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start',
      besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42',
      mennyegys: 'hó',
      menny: 1,
      nettoegysegar: '2669,29',
      nettoar: '2669,29',
      afakulcs: 5,
      afaertek: '133,46',
      bruttoar: '2802,75',
      id: 14,
    },
  ],
  {
    termeknev: 'Autóskártya',
    besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12',
    mennyegys: 'hó',
    menny: 1,
    nettoegysegar: '1000,00',
    nettoar: '1000,00',
    afakulcs: 27,
    afaertek: '270,00',
    bruttoar: '1270,00',
    id: 20,
  },
];
```

The problem is that if I want to read the data of "termeknev" I get the

```js
[  "Adatmegosztó",  null,  null,  "Autóskártya" ]
```

I think the problem is at the "null" is another array but I tried many ways and I cant fix it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you need the nested arrays? If not you can simply [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the outer array.

Comment: Share your code solution let's see what you're missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Flat

If you don't need to maintain the nested arrays you can flatten the outer array using [`Array#flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to retrieve the desired property.

```js
const input = [{ termeknev: 'Adatmegosztó', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '543,30', nettoar: '543,30', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '27,16', bruttoar: '570,46', id: 1, }, [{ termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '6000,00', nettoar: '6000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '1620,00', bruttoar: '7620,00', id: 2, }, { termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 3, }, { termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2669,29', nettoar: '2669,29', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '133,46', bruttoar: '2802,75', id: 4, }, { termeknev: 'Korlátlan sebesség&adat opció', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2362,20', nettoar: '2362,20', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '118,11', bruttoar: '2480,31', id: 5, },], [{ termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '6000,00', nettoar: '6000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '1620,00', bruttoar: '7620,00', id: 12, }, { termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 13, }, { termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2669,29', nettoar: '2669,29', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '133,46', bruttoar: '2802,75', id: 14, },], { termeknev: 'Autóskártya', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 20, },];

const termeknevFlat = input.flat().map(({ termeknev }) => termeknev);
console.log('Flat:', termeknevFlat);
```

##### Nested (known depth)

If you need to maintain the nested arrays and you know there are only 2 levels of nesting, you can use nested `map()` calls

```js
const input = [{ termeknev: 'Adatmegosztó', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '543,30', nettoar: '543,30', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '27,16', bruttoar: '570,46', id: 1, }, [{ termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '6000,00', nettoar: '6000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '1620,00', bruttoar: '7620,00', id: 2, }, { termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 3, }, { termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2669,29', nettoar: '2669,29', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '133,46', bruttoar: '2802,75', id: 4, }, { termeknev: 'Korlátlan sebesség&adat opció', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2362,20', nettoar: '2362,20', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '118,11', bruttoar: '2480,31', id: 5, },], [{ termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '6000,00', nettoar: '6000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '1620,00', bruttoar: '7620,00', id: 12, }, { termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 13, }, { termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2669,29', nettoar: '2669,29', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '133,46', bruttoar: '2802,75', id: 14, },], { termeknev: 'Autóskártya', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 20, },];

const termeknevNested = input.map(o =>
  Array.isArray(o)
    ? o.map(({ termeknev }) => termeknev)
    : o.termeknev
);
console.log('\nNested:', termeknevNested);
```

##### Recursive (arbitrary depth)

If the nesting can be arbitrarily deep you can write a recursive map function which accepts a callback.

```js
const input = [{ termeknev: 'Adatmegosztó', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '543,30', nettoar: '543,30', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '27,16', bruttoar: '570,46', id: 1, }, [{ termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '6000,00', nettoar: '6000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '1620,00', bruttoar: '7620,00', id: 2, }, { termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 3, }, { termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2669,29', nettoar: '2669,29', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '133,46', bruttoar: '2802,75', id: 4, }, { termeknev: 'Korlátlan sebesség&adat opció', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2362,20', nettoar: '2362,20', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '118,11', bruttoar: '2480,31', id: 5, }, [{ termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '6000,00', nettoar: '6000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '1620,00', bruttoar: '7620,00', id: 2, }, { termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 3, }, { termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2669,29', nettoar: '2669,29', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '133,46', bruttoar: '2802,75', id: 4, }, { termeknev: 'Korlátlan sebesség&adat opció', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2362,20', nettoar: '2362,20', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '118,11', bruttoar: '2480,31', id: 5, },]], [{ termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '6000,00', nettoar: '6000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '1620,00', bruttoar: '7620,00', id: 12, }, { termeknev: 'Üzleti elõfizetés', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 13, }, { termeknev: 'Vállalati Hipernet Start', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.42', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '2669,29', nettoar: '2669,29', afakulcs: 5, afaertek: '133,46', bruttoar: '2802,75', id: 14, },], { termeknev: 'Autóskártya', besorszam: 'TESZOR 61.20.12', mennyegys: 'hó', menny: 1, nettoegysegar: '1000,00', nettoar: '1000,00', afakulcs: 27, afaertek: '270,00', bruttoar: '1270,00', id: 20, },];


const recursiveMap = (arr, cb) =>
  arr.map((obj, i, _arr) =>
    Array.isArray(obj)
      ? recursiveMap(obj, cb)
      : cb(obj, i, _arr)
  )

const termeknevRecursive = recursiveMap(input, ({ termeknev }) => termeknev);
console.log('\nRecursive:', termeknevRecursive);
```

Comment: if i want to map more think "flat" in one array hoq can i do? I mean i want to refer to  "termeknev" and "bruttoar" and place next to each other in an object

Comment: You would simply destructure the wanted properties and return an object from the map call. `input.flat().map(({termeknev, bruttoar}) => ({termeknev, bruttoar}));`

Answer (score 0):

The second and third element in the data are type `array` not `object`.

So if you just get the value like `data[1].termeknev` it will return null because there is no property `termeknev` in `data[1]`. You need to acces it like `data[1][0].termeknev`.

If you are iterating through the data array, just check in each iteration if element is type `array`, if It is, you need to iterate through that nested array to get the actual values.